# Python Fabric - No hosts found

Tags: python, fabric

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It seems like a simple thing that should work. I can run the task "test_task" by itself and it works. If i run it as part of the "deploy_test" function then it prompts me with:
*No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:*

```
env.roledefs = {
    'test_servers': ['testserver1.domain.com', 'testserver2.domain.com']
}

@roles("test_servers")
def test_task():
    env.user = "test_user"
    sudo("sh /usr/bin/something", user="other_user")

def deploy_test():
    test_task()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decorator only works if you execute the task from `fab` command:

```
fab test_task
```

If you want to use the task `deploy_test`, you have many options:

1.- Execute `test_task` as a task, not as function. This is the way to go if you have other tasks that should be executed on `deploy_test()` on a different host list:

```
def deploy_test():
   execute(test_task)
```

2.-  Put the role decorator on `deploy_test()`:

```
@roles("test_servers")
def deploy_test():
   test_task()
```

Keep in mind that a python function is different from a fabric task. A fabric task do some stuff under the hood, like setting the host list, the user, and this state is keeped if you call python functions.

Comment: Hi! for me the `execute(test_task)` thing still causes the issue. I am using Fabric 1.13.2